# Create a new JSON file in QT5

Tags: json, qt5

Obviously Qt5 has better support for JSON. The Qt example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html explains how to parse and also modify JSON files or object, which is great.

But for my requirement I should create a completely new JSON file, so I can't use the methods to modify existing JSON parameters. Maybe I didn't understand the examples, but how can I create a completely new JSON object?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be rather straight forward:

```
QJsonObject myJsonObj;
myJsonObj["MyValue"] = 10;
QJsonDocument doc(myJsonObj);

QFile file("MyFile.json");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
file.write(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented));
```